# How to delete from table then delete what deleted rows referenced? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

What I would like to do is delete rows from `table 1` then delete from `table 2` rows that the deleted rows from `table 1` referenced with a foreign key.  I want to know if I could do this without out having to delete my foreign key on table 2 and recreating it with `on delete cascade`.

I'm not great with SQL and attempted 3 different approches without any success.

**1: Trying to delete from multiple tables at once**

```
delete from table1 a, table2 b where a.table2_id = b.id and a.column < 0;
```

**2: Delete with return**

```
delete from table2 where id in
   (delete from table1 where column < 0 returning table2_id as id);
```

**3: Create an array from select and use it to delete from both tables**

```
DECLARE
   arr integer[] :=  array(select table2_id from table1 where column < 0);
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
      delete from table1 where table2_id = m;
      delete from table2 where id = m;
   END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single statement using a writeable CTE

```
with t1_deleted as (
   delete from table1 where column < 0 
   returning table2_id as id
)
delete from table2 
where id in (select id from t1_deleted);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this if you can rearrange your delete.

Please try below updated function.

```
create table schema_name.table_name1 (id serial primary key, name text)
create table schema_name.table_name2(id bigint references schema_name.table_name1(id), mno bigint)

create or replace function schema_name.fn_test_f_k() returns void as $$
DECLARE
   c1 cursor for select id from schema_name.table_name1 where id = 1;
BEGIN
   for r IN c1
   LOOP
      delete from schema_name.table_name2 where id = r.id;
      delete from schema_name.table_name1 where id = r.id;
   END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;

select schema_name.fn_test_f_k();
```

Comment: You can use delete queries without function just mention rows to be delete in where condition.

Comment: Its just you need to first delete rows from foreign key table(table2)

Comment: but i cant delete table2 first cuz table1 references it.

Comment: Its just you need to delete first from foreign key table before deleting rows from primary key table.

Comment: `table1.table2_id = table2.id` table one references table two.

Comment: Im still getting an error `ERROR:  FOREACH ... SLICE loop variable must be of an array type
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at FOREACH over array`